# Save matlab plot as EMF-file in specific size

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I tried the following script in Matlab 2014b and 2015a, but the size of the EMF-file is not satisfactory:

```
fig = figure; bode(1/tf('s'));
set(fig,'PaperPositionMode','auto');
set(fig, 'Position', [0 0 400 300]);
print(fig,'test1','-dpng','-r0','-loose'); % here the result is a picture with 300 x 400 ->ok
print(fig,'test2','-dmeta','-r0','-loose'); % here the size is 215,19 x 286,69 -> not ok
```

I tried also to use:

```
set(fig,'PaperUnits','points','PaperPosition',[0 0 400 300])
```

But it does not change anything. It makes also no difference if '-loose' is used or not. Where is my mistake?

Edit: Can someone test the script in Matlab 2015b or 2013b?

Remark: Someone claimed that an EMF-graphic has not a size. It has one, because it is designed for printers where you exactly specifiy the size how it is printed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you determine the size? To my knowledge emf is a vector graphic without an actual size in pixels.

Comment: I insert it in Word and then look in the property original size. Edit: The same happens if I open it in Inkscape. (Background: The problem is that the font sizes in the figure do not fit if I change the size of the emf-graphic in Word) I would guess that there is something like a size of a emf because Word and Inkscape show the same size.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem using Matlab 2013a. Using the code above and just picking a random online service to convert to a raftered image (png), I end up with the right dimensions.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly the problem. In earlier versions the script worked. I tested yesterday also on Matlab 2015b. Same problem. If you search in the Internet, Matlab has swapped its rendering machine from zbuffer to openGl. But does someone knows a bug fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

*set()* behaviour changes whether you have multiple figures on screen.

I am on Mac, so I can't save EMF files, but since you saved `fig`, try `set()` with `fig` and not with `gcf` as first argument.

`gcf` is *get current figure* so if you have multiple figures on-screen you should pay attention. Although by saving the figure handle, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not the problem. I have only one figure. I tested it also with "fig" in "set". No difference.